# Angular Material 2 - Disable Ripple?

Tags: angular-material2

I'm currently working with md-tab-group (just updated to latest version yesterday)...

Does anyone know

1. if it is possible to **disable/configure Ripple on existing components** (md-tab-group in this case)? Latest version causes my tab headers to jump because ripple is calculating large values, solution is to add a small value for *md-ripple-max-radius* for md-tab-label directly in the template of MdTabGroup.
2. if there are plans to **remove min-width for md-tab-labels**? I'm working with a quite small tab group (only 300px width), therefore 160px min-width is not usable.

Thank you!

Comment: @Alireza has the correct answer posted for your question.  You should consider marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 92):

Use **disableRipple** as an attribute to disable ripples for the `md-tab-group` as **Angular2+** using the Angular material.

Just simply do something like this:

```
<md-tab-group disableRipple></md-tab-group>
```

Also if you are using the **latest Angular Material**, it's a little bit different like this below:

```
<mat-tab-group [disableRipple]="true"></mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: `[disableRipple]="true"` in Angular 5+

Comment: In order to disable ripple for first focused element, set its tabindex attribue greater than 1.

Comment: This is not working in Angular 7. Can't bind to 'disableRipple' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-horizontal-stepper'.

Comment: [disableRipple]="true" is still working in Angular 8

Comment: It gives error in browser console : 
add `MaterialStepper in @NgModule`

Answer (score 2):

The current version of **Angular** I'm now working on is **15.2.6**.
This is the only way it worked for me when using components like **MatStepper**:

1. In **`app.module.ts`**

   ```
   import {MatRippleModule, MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/core';**
   ```
2. In the decorator of **`@NgModule`**, you should provide this in the **`providers[]`** array:

   ```
   providers: [{provide: MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {disabled: true}}]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with two ways to override md styles based on another post. I had the exact same problem for tabs being too wide in a small tab group. It is still very experimental and might need further explanations but it has worked for me.

1. First solution using **Sass** styling

You can use */deep/* before the class you are trying to override

```css
/* your-component.component.scss file*/

/deep/ .md-tab-label {
  min-width: 0px; /* Or whatever value you wish */
  /* In some situations !important seems necessary */
}
```

```html
<!-- your-component.component.html -->
<!-- Template from Angular Material's Github Readme.md -->
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>
      The <em>best</em> pasta
    </template>
    <h1>Best pasta restaurants</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>
      <md-icon>thumb_down</md-icon> The worst sushi
    </template>
    <h1>Terrible sushi restaurants</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

2. Second solution with **pure css**

   - Create an *overrides.css* file that you link in your main *index.html* and then override the material classes here

```css
/* overrides.css */
.md-tab-label ,.md-tab-label-active {
  min-width: 0; /* same comments as the first solution */
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" content="text/css" href="overrides.css">
```

Both are kinda dirty, but the first one provides me a good solution to override a md component's style, keeping the alterations inside the concerned components (consider wrapping those components for local changes only).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove ripple and click effect in Angular v15 with Angular material v15 you can do it with the "disableRipple" property and some stylings.

```
<mat-checkbox
   formControlName="yes"
   disableRipple
   >Yes
</mat-checkbox>
```

Add styling rule to the styles.scss or styles.css:

```
   .mdc-checkbox__ripple { 
     display: none;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a **CSS-Grid** composed of several columns. In the last column, you have a `MaterialMenu` (activated by a `MaterialIconButton`).

In a different column, you choose to use an alternative `MaterialIcon` (without a button) and find that it fails to maintain proper vertical alignment within the grid layout as the window width decreases.

[image]

Consequently, you alter this `MaterialIcon` to a `MaterialIconButton` and see, that everything is perfectly vertically centered now.

[image]

Here are the div boxes (Chrome Debug CSS Extension shows vertical centering):

[image]

You now encounter **hover** and **ripple effects** on this `MaterialIconButton` (e.g. lightbulb), which may be deemed intrusive. In such scenarios, it is advisable to eliminate these effects:

**Import the necessary modules (excerpt):**

```
imports: [
  // ...
  MatIconModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatRippleModule,
],
```

**Disable Ripple like:**

```html
<div class="lightbulb-container">
  <button mat-icon-button [disableRipple]="true">
    <mat-icon>lightbulb</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

**Overwrite `Hover` & remove `Cursor` for this MatIconButton:**

```scss
  .lightbulb-container {
    button {
      cursor: initial;
      --mat-icon-button-state-layer-color: transparent;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisando en modo "Desarrollador" desde el navegador Edge, encontré que puedes quitarle ese efecto mediante CSS o SASS utilizando las propiedades que se usan para "ripple":

```
 .mat-mdc-icon-button
    border-radius: 0px
    --mat-icon-button-state-layer-color: transparent
    --mat-icon-button-ripple-color: transparent

// Para el cursor:
.mdc-icon-button
    cursor: default
```

Puedes ponerle "transparent" o "none".

Por favor califica esta respuesta si te sirvió.