# How to disable ripple effect in google material design web components

Tags: web, material-design

I use google material design web components. In some cases, components come with ripple enable as default. For example, the switch component has ripple by default. My question is how can I disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this **[disableRipple]="true"** to the component:

*Note this might only work from > Angular 4*

i.e.

```
<mat-tab-group class="tabs" [disableRipple]="true">
    <mat-tab>
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        Assigned Tasks
      </ng-template>
      <app-ongoingtasks></app-ongoingtasks>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

You can check this post: [Angular Material 2 - Disable Ripple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162195/angular-material-2-disable-ripple)

Hope this helps.
Regards

Comment: I don’t think it works for me because my site is nothing to do with angular at all. Anyway, I will give it a try.

Comment: Sorry Nero, i thought it was related to Angular, as i was searching for similar issues.